# Can I get the prev PHP version on Linux Server Before upgrade?

Tags: php, linux

Is there any way to know the prev PHP version which was installed on linux server before PHP upgrade?

The case is: After upgrading PHP to 5.4.30 some functions in scripts are not working. I want to downgrade PHP but I forget the prev version. Can you help in this?

Comment: Upgrading to PHP 5.4? Support ended for that a month ago - running it is dangerously insecure. I'd guess you were on 5.3, which is even more dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt this would happen as it would cause large scale applications to break. As far as knowing the previous PHP version installed there may be a PHP log file somewhere or left over folders from your previous PHP installation which may tell you what version you had.

Are you sure it's not just your scripts? Try using the error_reporting() function to find out what exactly is broken and then reply accordingly with that information, i'll try to assist.

Comment: "I highly doubt this would happen as it would cause large scale applications to break." Most PHP major versions (i.e. 5.3-->5.4) have at least some breaking changes. http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php

Comment: Hence why I asked him to provide me with his scripts.